# Prevent typing in Word content controls

Tags: ms-word

I am working with content control fields in Word 2013. Several of the fields are dropdowns, but I noticed that users can also type something into the field. Is there a way in word to prevent users from typing into these content control fields (and only select a value from the list)? Even if it includes a little bit of VB magic. I checked the Properties window of the content control fields and couldn't find an applicable setting to prevent typing only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content control I was using was not a true drop down, it was a combo box. The solution would be to delete the combo boxes and add drop downs in their place. This seems to work with Word 2007-2013.